# multiple images in extension using extbase and FAL

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am making a small extension with extension builder which has two models, companies and categories. Each has an images field which should, theoretically, hold ond or more images. I was following [this tutorial](http://t3-developer.com/extbase-fluid/extensions-erweitern/fal-in-eigenen-extensions/fal-in-typo3-extensions-verwenden/), and define the getImage() function as an ObjectStorage like this:

```
    /**
     * mypictures
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
     */
    protected $mypictures;

   /**
    * Returns mypictures
    *
    * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $postpictures
    */
    public function getMypictures() {
        return $this->mypictures;
    }
```

But the page just loads for about 30 seconds and then prints out nothing. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

edit: the timeout problem is gone. now it says: "ForViewHelper only supports arrays and objects implementing \Traversable interface"

Comment: Please provide the code snippets of your controller action and view (fluid template)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is just missing in your provided snippets, but you must initialize the storage object in your model:

```
public function __construct() {
    // Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
    $this->initStorageObjects();
}

/**
 * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function initStorageObjects() {
    $this->mypictures = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}
```

Then, clear the system cache and try again.